# Problem UIDocumentPickerViewController in iOS 14

Tags: swift, ios14

sorry for the question but i can't find a solution or i can't understand ...
until now I was using the function.

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        
        
         // Importo
         if controller.documentPickerMode == .import {
          
         my code
         }

       // Esporto
         if controller.documentPickerMode == .exportToService {
          may code
         }
```

now, .documentPickerMode in ios 14 is no longer present, how can I get the same result? or will he know if I come from import or export?

TKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have to use four different methods. Two for exporting and another two for opening types of documents you specify:

---

[Creates and returns a document picker that can export the types of documents you specify.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/3566730-init)

```
init(forExporting: [URL])
```

---

[Creates and returns a document picker that can export or copy the types of documents you specify.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/3566731-init)

```
init(forExporting: [URL], asCopy: Bool)
```

---

[Creates and returns a document picker that can open the types of documents you specify.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/3566732-init)

```
init(forOpeningContentTypes: [UTType])
```

---

[Creates and returns a document picker that can open or copy the types of documents you specify.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/3566733-init)

```
init(forOpeningContentTypes: [UTType], asCopy: Bool)
```

---

Then you switch the controller when it gets called:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {

    switch controller {
        case documentExporter:
            print("documentExporter")
        case documentImporter:
            print("documentImporter")
        default: break
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello,

thanks for the answer ok but when the method documentPicker (_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL] is called when I click on the document to load, and then perform some operations, now how can I do?

Comment: just switch the controller and check which controller is calling the method.

Comment: Thanks for your time
i put the switch in the but error notification method "Cannot find 'documentExporter' in scope"

Comment: @Francesco use the name of the controllers you have chosen